# What is the benefit of requestAnimationFrame(...paramList...)?

Tags: javascript

Question:

Why is the requestAnimationFrame called with this function? For example, if I was building a game what benefit would requestAnimationFrame be over just repainting the canvas.

code:

```
function main() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 1000);
    render();

    then = now;

    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};
```

All Code Below: (You would need 3 .jpg files)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    // Create the canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width  = 512;
    canvas.height = 480;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // Background image
    var bgReady = false;
    var bgImage = new Image();
    bgImage.onload = function () {
        bgReady = true;
    };
    bgImage.src = "background.png";

    // Hero image
    var heroReady = false;
    var heroImage = new Image();
    heroImage.onload = function () {
        heroReady = true;
    };
    heroImage.src = "hero.png";

    // Monster image
    var monsterReady = false;
    var monsterImage = new Image();
    monsterImage.onload = function () {
        monsterReady = true;
    };
    monsterImage.src = "monster.png";

    // Game objects
    var hero = {
        speed: 256 // movement in pixels per second
    };

    var monster = {};
    var monstersCaught = 0;

    // Handle keyboard controls
    var keysDown = {};

    addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    }, false);

    addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
        delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
    }, false);

    // Reset the game when the player catches a monster
    var reset = function () {
        hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
        hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

        // Throw the monster somewhere on the screen randomly
        monster.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
        monster.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
    };

    // Update game objects
    var update = function (modifier) {
        if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
            hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
            hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
            hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
            hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
        }

        // Are they touching?
        if (hero.x <= (monster.x + 32) && 
            monster.x <= (hero.x + 32) && 
            hero.y <= (monster.y + 32) && 
            monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)
        ) {
            ++monstersCaught;
            reset();
        }
    };

    // Draw everything
    var render = function () {
        if (bgReady) {
            ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
        }

        if (heroReady) {
            ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
        }

        if (monsterReady) {
            ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
        }

        // Score
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
        ctx.font      = "24px Helvetica";
        ctx.textAlign    = "left";
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        ctx.fillText("Goblins caught: " + monstersCaught, 32, 32);
    };

    // The main game loop
    /*var main = function () {
        var now = Date.now();
        var delta = now - then;

        update(delta / 1000);
        render();

        then = now;

        // Request to do this again ASAP
        requestAnimationFrame(main);
    };*/

    // The main game loop -- This is the second way of doing this
    function main() {
        var now = Date.now();
        var delta = now - then;

        update(delta / 1000);
        render();

        then = now;

        // Request to do this again ASAP
        requestAnimationFrame(main);
    };

    // Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
    var w = window;
    requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

    // Let's play this game!
    var then = Date.now();
    reset();
    main();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because repeatedly calling `main` would cause the browser to hang until it gave up with a stack overflow error.

`requestAnimationFrame` simply says "do this when the browser is ready to render another frame".

Comment: So you would always want to call requestAnimationFrame which is that a method of window.requestAnimationFrame(..).  Why does it use the date method.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is kinda like saying "okay, we're done here, finish up what you need to do and then do this afterwards".

Comment: So, why use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout(13)`?